# iOS: InAppBrowser cordova issue with copy paste context menu

Tags: ios, cordova, cordova-plugins, inappbrowser

I am facing very strange issue in **iOS:cordova InAppBrowser** using target (_blank). once I open the page inside it, copy and paste context menu appears but if you tap it, it does not work.

**Note**: this only happens in iOS, Android is working fine.